# Excel Worksheet formulas that figure out the row it is on to use in cell reference calculations

Tags: excel, macos

I have a worksheet with a large number of tables. Every other table is formatted the same. Each row has set columns that will not change with regard to the formula. Say... =(A * B / G) - D

I'm trying to figure out a way to write a Worksheet formula that I can cut and paste without having to alter the row reference in the formula for it to work. That way I can copy and paste the formula into each table since I cannot click and drag it down the whole worksheet.

Ideally, I'd like to keep a list of formulas in a text file that I could just cut and past and not have to alter. I would be really cool if I could do something similar for using UDFs that can figure out the Range(Cells()) location on its own.

I'm using . Thanks!

Comment: So put this in the first row of a new sheet: `=($A1 * $B1 / $G1) - $D1` Then copy and paste the **cell not the formula** itself and excel will automatically change the row reference to the row in which the cell is pasted.

Comment: I was thinking the same Scott, but you answered it much more eloquently

Answer (score 0):

```
=ROW()
```

but from your description I am not sure why you can not copy something like $A1 down and let the 1 update as it goes down each row.  Take a look at what the effect of the $ symbol before the column or cell reference does.  It prevents the column letter and/or row number from changing as cells are copied from one location to another.

`ROW()` will return the row number of what row it is in, or the row number of a reference if you supply the reference address:

`ROW(AS134`) will return 134.

To use this, you would most likely need to combine it with something like `INDIRECT`:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&ROW())
```

That formula would reference column A and the same row as wherever the formula was placed.  HOWEVER, `INDIRECT` is a bad choice if you are using it frequently as its a volatile function and will recalculate anytime something on the worksheet changes.  As per Scott Craner's suggestion,  `INDEX` is a non volatile function so it will not force the recalculations and would look something  like:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROW())
```